# Invert pandas dataframe and concatenate the result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two-column pandas dataframe

```
source |  target
----------------
1         3
2         4
2         1
```

This represents the edge list of a graph. As it stands, the graph is directed. I want to transform it to an undirected graph, so I need the "complementary" edges, so as to obtain:

```
source |  target
----------------
1         3
3         1
2         4
4         2
2         1
1         2
```

Is there any way I can do this directly in Pandas, without using graph libraries, such as networkx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way I can do this directly in Pandas, without using graph libraries, such as networkx

We can reverse the df using `df.iloc` and then append using `df.append`

```
out = df.append(pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,::-1].to_numpy(),index=df.index
      ,columns=df.columns)).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or using `np.flip`:

```
(df.append(pd.DataFrame(np.flip(df.to_numpy(),axis=1),
 index=df.index,columns=df.columns)).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True))
```

---

```
print(out)

   source  target
0       1       3
1       3       1
2       2       4
3       4       2
4       2       1
5       1       2
```

Note: If there are more columns , you can take a subset of the dataframe as `sub_df = df[['source','target']]` and replace `df` with `sub_df` i the code.

Another Idea proposed by @ShubhamSharma using `set_axis` which renames the columns on the fly:

```
(df.append(df.iloc[:, ::-1].set_axis(df.columns, 1,inplace=False))
   .sort_index().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: @Qubix Glad I could help :) Cheers..!!

Comment: @anky short cut for method 1 `df.append(df.iloc[:, ::-1].set_axis(df.columns, 1)).sort_index()`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Nice trick, only `inplace=False` should be added to avoid warning in lower version of pandas : `df.append(df.iloc[:, ::-1].set_axis(df.columns, 1,inplace=False)).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)` Thank you :-)